# Transformation to Pandas dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, function, dataframe

[image]I converted a csv to a pandas dataframe, but when I run the code, it can't found the columns. The purpose of having my transformation in separated functions is because I wanna be able to unittest my functions.

```
import pandas as pd

def main():
    inputDf = pd.read_csv("android-games.csv", header=0, delim_whitespace=True)

    df = inputDf.transform(model)

    print(df)


def model(df):
    df\
        .transform(add_col)\
        .transform(test_col)

def add_col(df):
    df["price_1"] = df["price"] + 1

def test_col(df):
    df["rank_1"] = df["rank"] + 1


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

That's my error, i'm guessing my code is not well structured :

> File
> "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.8/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pandas/core/indexes/range.py",
> line 358, in get_loc
> raise KeyError(key) KeyError: 'price'

Comment: We will need to see the csv to help you

Comment: @xjcl just added a screenshot of the csv

Comment: print `df.columns` seems like you have spaces in the column name.

Answer (score 0):

I am not clear why you are using transform as I think you can get the result in a much simpler way as follows (unless I have misunderstood what you are trying to achieve):

```py
df = pd.read_csv("android-games.csv", header=0, delim_whitespace=True)
df["price_1"] = df["price"] + 1
df["rank_1"] = df["rank"] + 1
print(df)
```

Comment: I agree with you but my ETL is gonna get bigger and I'm trying to have all my transformation inside functions to be able to unittest my code.

Comment: Thats fine but then just have functions like:
```def do_transform(df):
   [code to modify]
   return df
```